# Related rates word problem regarding vehicles

Tags: calculus

Two straight highways are perpendicular to each other. Car A is 3 km from the intersection and is moving at 100 km/h toward the junction. On the other highway, Car B is 5 km from the intersection and is moving at 90 km/h toward the junction. At what rate is the distance between the two cars changing at that instant?

The answer I got is 128.6239...km/h.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's what I got too. You should specify that the distance is *decreasing* at the rate of 128...km/h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$s^2 = s_A^2 + s_B^2$ by Pythagoras' Theorem.

Differentiating wrt $t$ implicitly and simplifying,

$s\frac{ds}{dt} = s_A\frac{ds_A}{dt}+s_B\frac{ds_B}{dt}$

Initial $s = \sqrt{3^2 + 5^2} = \sqrt {34} \mathrm{km}$. Putting the relevant values in and rearranging, we get the required answer (the original question asker's answer is correct).

Comment: @Blobd you're welcome. Please consider accepting the answer if you found it helpful. :)